# Overview bar in Eclipse Classic

Tags: eclipse

I am having a strange problem with Eclipse Classic Indigo where I cannot see the overview bar.    I did some searching and could not find any option to enable or disable it, but it appears to be disabled in my Eclipse.  I was wondering if anyone had a fix for this?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what do you mean by `overview bar`? Do you refer to the top tool-bar, top menu-bar, annotation-ruler in the left side of the editor or the overview-ruler on the right side of the editor?

Comment: A screenshot would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOH!  New Mac User having a windows moment -- I have the answer to this question.  I was looking for the top menu bar INSIDE the eclipse dialog (i.e. just above the icons) but like everything else mac it locates the top menu bar outside the actual dialog at the top of your monitor view.

Hope this helps someone else :)